# Type casting in C - Ints and Char*

Tags: c, arrays, casting, void, void-pointers

Say I am given a `void* data` array, and asked to populate it with info of 2 different datatypes: an array of int's and a string.

```
void* data;
int numbers[9];
char* title;
```

I understand that to input the numbers into the data array, I need to typecast it like this:

```
memcpy((int*)data, numbers, sizeof(numbers));
```

But what do I do if I want to put `title` in the address after numbers gets copied into data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming `res` actually means `data` from your first snippet ?

Comment: You have to calculate the correct address for the starting point of the title? (in this case after the 9 integer values) Or are you asking how to do the pointer arithmetic for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no need to type cast, since `memcpy()` works with `void *`:

```
memcpy(data, numbers, sizeof numbers);
```

Also no need for `()`s with `sizeof` when applied to anything that is not a type name.

For the second part, you need to compute the address:

```
memcpy((char *) data + sizeof numbers, title, 1 + strlen(title));
```

Here I assume that `title` is a 0-terminated string. The cast of `data` to `char *` is necessary since you can't do pointer arithmetic with `void *`.

Comment: I was thinking that's the case but was doing it in an over complicated way. thanks a bunch!!